# How to find out HDMI version with a Samsung laptop?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, resolution, hdmi, intel-graphics

I have a Samsung NP900X3E-A02US: http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP900X3E-A02US-specs

How can I find out what is the version of the micro HDMI port? There is no written documentation anywhere. I would like to know if it's v1.3 (most likely) or v1.4 in order to figure out what kind of maximum external resolution I can get, aka. 2560x1440 (most likely) or 4k @50/60Hz?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison

The graphics chipset is "Intel® HD Graphics 4000".

Comment: It is going to be HDMI 1.4.  [Source](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics/).  Took me about 2 minutes of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3rd generation Intel® Core™ processor family
(Intel® HD graphics 4000 / 2500) supports the following resolutions.

> DisplayPort* 1.2 / eDP*
>                        H-Processors: 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz (Ultra-HD)
>    U-Processors: 3200 x 2000 @ 60 Hz, 3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz
>    Y-Processors: 2560 x 1600 @ 60 Hz
>    DVI: 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz
>
> HDMI* with HDCP Version 1.4 (3-D, Deep Color, premium audio, auto lip-sync)

Comment: I don't think I have 4th generation and 4000 is not in the list you are mentioning. lspci reports: http://pastebin.com/DVgnvMsa

Comment: It still supports it.....I didn't even have to change the image.